# How can I concatenate two images in one? Without any framework, only with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, ecmascript-6, concatenation

I need some help with code review and re-translate it out of jQuery to plain JS.

I've tried to  translate this into pure JS, but I don't get clearly why it doesn't work. If needed, I can show what I've made.

1. After the user selects an image from the first input, it should be rendered on canvas.
2. After the user selects an image from the second input, it should be rendered on the same canvas to the right of the first image.
3. Images should be rendered in scale, so two pictures will have the same height on canvas, but with the original aspect ratio.
4. User can select images in any order, but rendering order should stay the same: image from first input appears on canvas before image from the second input.
5. Inputs should accept only images.

```js
$('.file1, .file2').on('change', function() {
  var reader = new FileReader(),
    imageSelector = $(this).data('image-selector');

  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      imageIsLoaded(e, imageSelector)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});

$('.btn-merge').on('click', merge);

function imageIsLoaded(e, imageSelector) {
  $(imageSelector).attr('src', e.target.result);
  $(imageSelector).removeClass('hidden');
};

function merge() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    imageObj1 = new Image(),
    imageObj2 = new Image();

  imageObj1.src = $('.image1').attr('src');
  imageObj1.onload = function() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 328, 526);
    imageObj2.src = $('.image2').attr('src');;
    imageObj2.onload = function() {
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
      ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, 15, 85, 300, 300);
      var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      $('.merged-image').attr('src', img);
      $('.merged-image').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: You can click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56459580/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are too many broadly defined terms / requests.  Please keep the question specific to one issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the onload before changing source and not inside another onload

```js
function merge() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    imageObj1 = new Image(),
    imageObj2 = new Image();

  imageObj1.onload = function() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0, 328, 526);
  }
  imageObj2.onload = function() {
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, 15, 85, 300, 300);
    var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    $('.merged-image').attr('src', img);
    $('.merged-image').removeClass('hidden');
  }
  imageObj1.src = $('.image1').attr('src');
  imageObj2.src = $('.image2').attr('src');
}
```